# Using "Mix of" with one object

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

"Mix of" is most frequently used to show that two or more items are included in the creation of something. Is it still grammatically correct to use "mix of" when there's only one item, but the item is a category or in the plural?

For example:

> Apple is the only company that offers products via a mix of in-house technologies.

It seems like it would make more sense if it was:

> Apple is the only company that offers products composed entirely of in-house technologies.

However, is this truly a grammar issue or not?

Comment: The two sentences don't mean the same thing. The first talks about the technologies used to offer the products, the second is about the technologies that compose the products.

Comment: There's no grammatical problem with the first sentence. You can say "mix of ingredients", "mix of flavors", "mix of animals" -- any collective plural will work.

Comment: @barmar, so then it would appear to just be an ear issue.

Comment: What do you mean by *is this truly a grammar question*? There is nothing ungrammatical about either sentence—although, as said, they mean different things. (And it's not because of the use of *mix* in the first. It's because you switched *via* to *composed*.)

Comment: I think your instinct is right.  It should say mix of in-house and "out-of-house" technologies.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I meant is it a grammatical issue or an ear issue: is there a rule issue or do I just not like the way it sounds. Sometimes those two things align, but often time they don't.

Comment: @Karlomanio And what if the product is made available through a combination of five *in-house* technologies—and no out-of-house technologies at all? It's still a mix of several in-house technologies that have been used.